# Typescript generic interface circular reference

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

```js
interface Renderer<T extends Data> {
    data: T;
}

interface Data<T extends Renderer> {
    renderer: T;
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=7&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoRAE2tAPAFWQgA9IsBnZAETjDgD5kBvAWAChlPlNa4AuZPgDc7AL7t2oSLEQoadAkVIZMldFhxRGrDlygrNA4WPZA)

How to deal with this circular reference generic type in Typescript?

Comment: How do you expect to use this type?

Comment: The answer here depends quite heavily on your use case.  Could be [any of these](https://tsplay.dev/WYk2dN) or something else.  Can you please include a [mre] that demonstrates some intended usages of these?  I mean, if you have a value `r` of type `Renderer<?>`, do you *require* that `r.data.renderer` be of the same exact type?  If so, can you show how that requirement matters with some code that does bad things if it's not true?

Answer (score 0):

Generic Interfaces needs to be instantiated at the time of its usage

Hence the syntax should be

`interface A<T extends B<U>>`

And, Circular references are design limitations for few generic types if they lead to deadlock

You can check for better explanation here
[Issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41164#issuecomment-712418462)